# Add Windows Context Menu file command for "git difftool %1"

Tags: git, contextmenu, beyondcompare4

I am trying to add a file context menu option to execute *git difftool %1* (which is configured to use Beyond Compare 4).  I've got the context menu showing up with the icon I want but can't get Beyond Compare to pop up with the file diff.

I've tried setting the default string value to the following but it didn't work.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\BeyondCompare.Diff\command
(Default)
   = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
   = cmd /c git difftool %1
   = "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" /dir %v. git difftool %1
```

And here is the registry key to show the above command in the file context menu.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\BeyondCompare.Diff
(Default) = Git Diff
Icon = C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe
```

What should I set my command string to so this works?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create a custom context menu entry, it might be easier to use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) to provide context menu access to Git, then configure TortoiseGit to use Beyond Compare as an external diff and merge tool.